# MVC - Search Through Millions of Record Slow C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm running into a problem where I query through millions of record and it's taking a while. The query is pretty simple, but it takes anywhere between 8-12 seconds to come back to me. Is there a way to increase its performance? Down below is my code:

```
List<Product> AllProducts;

var item = from m in db.Products
           select m;

item = item.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(SearchKeyword));

AllProducts = item.ToList();
AllProducts = AllProducts.OrderBy(a => a.UPC).ToList();

return View(AllProducts);
```

Comment: How many elements are in `AllProducts` after `item.ToList()`?

Comment: For starters, you can simplify all of this to just one line: `return View(db.Products.Where(p => p.Title.Contains(SearchKeyword)).OrderBy(p => p.UPC).ToList());`  But aside from that, when you step through this in your debugger is there a specific operation which proves to be the bottleneck?

Comment: You should do ToList() only once. ToList() goes to the database and gets the data. Maybe the order by is faster on the database with an index.

order by on the ArrayList does an inmemory sort. You won't use the index on the database.

Comment: An index on `Title` in the database might help. I'm not DBA but you can trial the idea.

Comment: Even without sorting, it still takes a good amount of time to come back.

Comment: If this is Microsoft SQL Server then you can put a FULL TEXT Index on `Title` and that would definitely speed it up but it might be overkill. And the syntax would be different than what you get with Contains so you would likely want a stored procedure.

Comment: `Contains` translates to `like '%...%'` in sql. So you must use full text search to speed up query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make a mistake by getting records and then sort them. In my solution, sorting method has been added to database query. Database's sorting method is much much faster than entityframework's sorting method. So you can take records a bit faster like this :

```
List<Product> AllProducts = db.Products.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(SearchKeyword))
                                       .OrderBy(a => a.UPC)
                                       .ToList();

return View(AllProducts);
```

### --------------------

**On the other hand,** you can add index to Title column in your database. It accelerates the result.

Comment: I end up adding index to the column. It works. Thanks.